# deleting a 2D array of ints, set pointer to null in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

For an upcoming midterm, one of our practice problems was to write a function that will delete a 2D array of ints and set the pointer to NULL. I thought I knew how to do this but some other people in the class said some stuff that really confused me (they said we should use triple pointers so that we can modify the array, but isn't an array basically a pointer in itself? so wouldn't a **array be equivalent to a triple pointer?). Is my function correct?

```
void cleanUp(int** array, int numRows, int numCols) {
  for (int i = 0; i < numRows; ++i) {
    free((*array)[i]);
  }
  free(*array);
  *array = NULL;
}
```

Comment: An array is not a pointer, though an array may *decay* to a pointer in some cases. And you need to provide more information to decide whether your code is correct (a [mcve] for starters)

Comment: If you enable compiler warnings, you'll obtain some evidence as to whether this code is correct.

Comment: Show how code intends to call `cleanUp()`.

Comment: Detail: `int** array` is not a "2D array of ints", but a "pointer to pointer to int" - some may call a dynamic 2D array.    `int (*p)[3][4]` is an example of a pointer to a 2D array.

Answer (score 1):

You will first delete all the individual rows (containing `int`'s) and then the chunk of `int*`'s  will be deleted.

```
void cleanUp(int** array, int numRows, int numCols) {
  for (int i = 0; i < numRows; ++i) {
    free(array[i]); // deleting the individual arrays 
  }
  free(array); // deleting array of `int*`
}
```

In case of jagged array the `free`-ing would be opposite of how you allocated the complete jagged array.

First you allocate space for `numRow` `int*`'s.
Then for each `int*` you will allocate `numCol` `int`'s.

Now you do exact opposite of what you did:

1. Delete all the `int`'s first.
2. Then do the `int*`'s.

The reason for this ordering is that if you delete the `int*`-s first then there will be memory leak. You are not freeing the memory space for storing `int`'s at the same time you are losing the reference to it. That's why this reverse order of de-allocating memory.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to set the pointer to NULL as well, then yes, indeed you will need to use an `int ***` parameter in your function, and pass it the address of the pointer variable you want to clean up.

```
void cleanUp(int*** parray, int numRows, int numCols) {
    int **array = *parray;
    for (int i = 0; i < numRows; ++i) {
        free(array[i]);
    }
    free(array);
    *parray = NULL;
}
```

Note that `numCols` isn't used, so could be removed, unless you need to use it for further clean-up.

To explain the usage, assume there is a variable `int **thearray;` that has been set up to point to (the first element of) a dynamically allocated array of `int *` that is `numRows` elements long, and that each of `thearray[0]`, `thearray[1]`, ..., `thearray[numRows - 1]` has been set up to point to (the first element of) a dynamically allocated array of `int` that is `numCols` elements long.  Then calling `cleanUp(&thearray);` will free each row of `int` (that were pointed to by `thearray[0]`, ..., `thearray[numRows - 1]`), free the array of `int *` (that was pointed to by the `thearray` variable), and set the `thearray` variable itself to `NULL`.  The function does not know about the `thearray` variable, but its `parray` parameter points to it, so it can set it to `NULL` indirectly.

Comment: I got the call to `free` in the loop wrong originally (blindly copied from the original code!), but I've corrected it now.

Answer (score 0):

This is also a question of memory alignment. You could interpret a linear sequence of ints (int *) as a 2D, 3D, or n-D array if calculating the propper offset. So it is not necessary to use triple-pointers. A pointer has no direct mapping to an array but every array variable is a pointer to the first value (or pointer value for nested arrays).